# Ubuntu 20.04 Grub replaced by Debian Grub, UI changed to xfce and the VM does not connect to the network

Tags: debian, ubuntu, grub, network-interface, xfce

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a virtual machine hosted on VirtualBox software in Windows 10. Things were fine for a few months since install, then in the last couple days after a power outage, the system only shows Debian Grub options.
It only boots into Xfce UI. I can still login as the main user and I checked that all my files exist. But there is no network.

I tried booting with a live CD, and the networking works in a live session.

I have tried running the Boot Repair but get an error - "The system is in Bios-compatibilty mode...."

Here is a pastebin link to the boot info
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xMg8MjCrdj/

I am lost as to how I can revert back to the Ubuntu desktop where all my services were accessible and the networking was working.

I have spent a few hours googling this and none of the suggestions have worked. I have tired modifying grub.cfg, running boot-repair.
The closest explanation similar to the issue I found in at this link but it has no solution.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/quest...-default-os-to

Any pointers to get this resolved will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Update:
On Debian boot, the icon says Xubuntu. Did it somehow update to Xubuntu? I am not sure how I did that.
When is shows the login prompt, it momentarily shows the ubuntu background and switches to xfce background.
Logging in as other user (my admin) still shows xfce desktop with no networking.

I may have upgraded and caused this.

Comment: So, IPs, Links, and routes look normal/correct? What is the relevant part of the output of the commands showing these? Why, and what did you change regarding grub? That should normally not be necessary to "fix" networking issues in scenarios like yours.

Comment: @AlexStragies, i started looking at grub as the VM booted into xfce interface rather than the gdm interface. Also the grub options prior to the issue used to show Ubuntu, but now they show Debian. Regarding networking, there is no activity and no ip address acquired by the network interface. I have confirmed that the "cable connected" checkbox is checked. Networking works fine when in Ubuntu Live CD mode.
I can't understand how the UI interface switched to xfce and grub options to debian.

Comment: The reference to Debian in Grub is probably just the kernel 5.8.0 - which by coincidence is the version that Ubuntu 20.04 uses.

Comment: @JeremyBoden, why would that cause the UI to change to xfce and stop the networking from working?

Comment: We had a good discussion on ubuntu forums and decided to revert to an old backup as this was not going any further. here is a link to that discussion if someone is interested.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2463549